# Retrieve posts by custom taxonomy child on parent taxonomy page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So from the parent taxonomy view:

- **Child 1**

  - post
  - post
  - post
- **Child 2**

  - post
  - post
  - post
  - post
- **Child 3**

  - post
  - post
  - post
  - post

---

I've scoured the internet for a solution to this, but nothing seems to be working. I'm able to successfully echo the term ID, but when I pass that into the query it returns nothing.

```html
<?php
    $terms = get_terms( 'ht_kb_category' );
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if ($term->parent != 0) {
                echo '<li><h1>' . $term->name . '</h1></li>';

                $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array (
                            'taxonomy' => 'ht_kb_category',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                        )
                    ),
                ) );

                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

                echo '<p>'. the_title() .'</p>';

                endwhile;

                /* Restore original Post Data
                 * NB: Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the
                 * original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset.
                */
                wp_reset_postdata();

            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution after some detective work using the custom taxonomy URL. I was missing the 'post_type' and needed to query **'tag_id'** instead of 'term_id'.

```html
<?php $current_term_id = $hkb_current_term_id ?>

            <?php
            $myposts = get_posts(array(
                'showposts' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'ht_kb',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'ht_kb_category',
                    'field' => 'tag_id',
                    'terms' => $current_term_id)
                ))
            );

            echo '<ul>';

            foreach ($myposts as $mypost) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($mypost->ID) ?>"><?php echo $mypost->post_title ?></a></li>
            <?php }
            echo '</ul>';
            ?>
```